# Code architecture of service interface and service impl classes spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I found out that in an MVC pattern, there are mainly 4 classes; the controller, the service, the service impl and repo.

Service is an interface and service impl implements service class and contains all the logical codes. The structure would be something like :-

`Service` interface

```
Service{

public void someMethod();

}
```

`ServiceImpl` class

```
 ServiceImpl implements Service{
  public void someMethod(){
   //do something

   }    
 }
```

But when we want to access the service impl codes from controller, we call the method of service class as :-

```
@Autowired 
Service service;

Object obj =  service.someMethod();
```

How does the controller execute code of `ServiceImpl` class

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is basically how Spring works:

The service implementation should be a Spring bean (it either has to have a `@Component` or `@Service` annotation, or should be defined in a Spring XML configuration file), so that Spring will find it and register it in the Spring application context.

Then you use dependency injection, through the `@Autowired` annotation, to inject the implementation of the service into the controller. This means that Spring will look at your controller, it will find the `@Autowired` annotation on the `service` member variable and initialize it with a bean that it finds in the application context, which will be the instance of the service implementation class that it has registered earlier. So, after Spring is done, `service` will refer to the instance of `ServiceImpl`.

See the Spring Framework reference documentation for information on how dependency injection works with Spring: [The IoC container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans)

Comment: So what will happen if we implement the `Service` interface with multiple classes? Whose implementation code will get executed.

Comment: If you have multiple Spring beans which implement `Service` then you will get an error when you start the application, because Spring doesn't know which one to choose. There are ways to tell Spring which one to choose, for example using `@Qualifier` or `@Primary`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir. But why spring uses that kind of patttern? I think in a normal `mvc` pattern, there is no necessary role of an interface class. It is needed just to force the `ServiceImpl` classes to implement some methods.

Comment: The interface is not absolutely necessary for Spring. It would have worked exactly the same without the interface. But the point of having the interface is to separate the implementation so that you have less coupling, and it makes it easier to, for example, inject a mock implementation of the service for unit testing.

Comment: Say you have a StudentService which save  to MySQL today.Later you might get a new requirement to save to Mongo plus Elastic Search.If you have just service class,you have to modify existing service class.If you had an interface you just add another implementation.You can plug that new implementation from another dependency even without changing any code line.Say you need both functionality but select the functionality based on a startup command line parameter.Then you can have multiple implementations and choose at runtime depending on some qualifier.I think maintainability is the key here.

Comment: Right, but not exactly, you can refer to ServiceImpl directly, it will serve the purpose, difference is only when ServiceImpl is not part of current module or any dependency, but final bundled project will have its implementation through some sibling module probably

Answer (score 5):

Basic idea behind having this kind of architecture is little different than just spring convention.

Lets say tomorrow you decide, you dont want to have single application for both projects, and go into one deployment for webapp and another for service
Example
UserService
WebApp

so for WebApp to connect to UserService it will have to make http requests to get any kind of data. then you will have to change all your WebApp code to make it compatible to new changes. For example instead directly calling method of Service you will call httpClient. To avoid this rework what you can do is, Using interface Service you implement your own ServiceImpl and make all http request in there, rest remains intact.

Similar stuff will be done in UserService, it will have its own ServiceImpl as before but will be called in Controller as a singleton object.

Your answer : 
You can refer to ServiceImpl directly, it will serve the purpose, difference is only when ServiceImpl is not part of current module or any dependency, but final bundled project will have its implementation through some sibling module probably

Answer (score 3):

When you use the annotation *@Autowired*, Spring will automatically search in its application context a candidate to be injected in the controller. A valid candidate should be a concrete class marked as a Spring bean, using annotation *@Service* for example.

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to spring but it is a general practice in the Object Oriented Programming. Whenever we are consuming the unknown other object (in your case Service), we want to refer it via the contract i.e Interface.

Let's take a real life example.If you want to use the Washing Machine, You would like to use it via its Interface because it will hide the complexity involved inside and provide you the implementation (Abstraction).

In the Spring way, let's say if we use a Interface and ServiceImpl classes and in the Controller you call like :

```
@Autowire
private Service service
```

You are saying:

```
Service service = new ServiceImpl();
```

Think for a while, you might have many implementations like ServiceImpl1, ServiceImpl2 ... etc based on versioning and uses.(This is same like you might have many brand of Washing Machine like IFB, L.G, etc) so if you want to use a particular implementation like:

```
Service service = new ServiceImpl2();
```

Same thing in spring

```
@AutoWired
@Qualifier("ServiceImpl2")
Service service;
```

In this way you can achieve both the **Abstraction** and **Polymorphism**

Answer (score 0):

@Controller - Controller is an entry point where you consume request coming from User Interface, and define a bunch of services, and dump a requestmapping URI path which tells what request is coming in to backend, what to return. Then, you create bunch of services where you write bunch of interfaces, and then you can go on, and create bunch of ServiceImplementation files, and then DAO.
Note on Autowired :it automatically brings instance that you specify in
@Service - Particular class is to be treated as service, used for writing DAO transactions.
@Autowired brings an 'instance' you need from somewhere, usually we try to find 'services' that you want from Autowired annotation, then you can add @qualifier to avoid confusion of what specific instance to bring out of similar beans.